# Get shipping country during cart view - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to get the chosen shipping country when on the cart / checkout (so before the order is placed).
This is to determine if an extra fee (above the normal shipping costs) must be added.

How can i get the chosen country for this function?
I use it in an if-function (in this example for the country 'Belgium'):

```
 ` elseif ($total >= $min_order and $chosen_shippingcountry = 'BE') {$fees = 10;}`
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Regards,
Cedric

Answer (score 14):

If I am not wrong, you are looking for the code to get shipping country set on WooCommerce cart / checkout page. Below code is tested till WooCommerce 2.4.

Method #1:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()
```

Method #2

```
WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()
```

Note that there are [major changes](https://www.xadapter.com/how-to-setup-shipping-zones-on-woocommerce-2-6/) on shipping side from WooCommerce 2.6. But from the GitHub [reference](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_shipping_country), it should work.

Comment: comfirm both of method it is still working on Woocommerce Version 3.4.5